# Good way to convert JSON to Array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i am trying to convert a json response to array in action script 3.

This is my JSON response:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "klistid": 8017,
    "name": "List item name",
    "description": "List item description",
    "type": 1,
    "offset": 300,
    "req": "gfi"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "klistid": 8018,
    "name": "List item name",
    "description": "List item description",
    "type": 1,
    "offset": 600,
    "req": "gfi"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "klistid": 8019,
    "name": "List item name",
    "description": "List item description",
    "type": 1,
    "offset": 900,
    "req": "gfi"
}]
```

and this is my ac3 code:

```
    function GetLists()
    {
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:51318/api/List/1");
    var ret:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    ret.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(e:Event)
    {
        var jsonData:Object = JSON.decode(ret.data);
        for (var i:String in jsonData)
        {
        trace(i + ": " + jsonData[i]);
        }
    });
    ret.load(req);
    }
```

I assigned this function to a button but whenever i click that button nothing happens. I put traces in ac3 code when it enters the for loop code just stops and does nothing. I just want to convert this json string to an array or list to iterate through in it. I've already seen some posts about converting JSON strings to arrays but i have tried them all still nothing worked yet.

Thanks

Comment: You already have the array when you decode.  `var jsonData:Object = JSON.decode(ret.data)`  So if you did `trace(jsonData is Array)` you'll get true.    So you can access your objects by doing  `jsonData[0].id` etc.

Comment: Also, you can just use the built in top level JSON function - which is `JSON.parse(ret.data)`;

Comment: @LDMS Oddly, i got false when i checked my jsonData with `trace(jsonData is Array)` is my json string wrong ?

Comment: Nope, I just tried it as posted and got true (as an array).   Try tacing out `ret.data` and see what you get, maybe the issue lies there.  Also, did you switch to using `JSON.parse` (take out all references to as3corelib's JSON)

Comment: The as3corelib JSON class is not as performant as the native one, you should definitely switch.

Comment: @LDMS as you said the issue was about the json string itself. I use asp.net web api and JSON.NET to return my json strings. JSON.net adds string escapes in the json string. For many languages it is a valid method but obviously it is not for actionscript because, those escapes arrives to as3 in the raw json string. So, `JSON.decode` didn't even work correctly.

Comment: Did you try it in the native JSON.parse method though?

Comment: @LDMS didn't work either. I had to remove backslashes and starting - ending double quotes from the json string to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between your json data and the way to try to iterate on it.

Your data is an array with one element but you try to iterate on that one element like it should contain your objects id:1, 2, 3, etc ... Well of course it doesn't.

Instead remove the wrapper array from your json data or if you don't want to then:

```
var data:Object = jsonData[0];
for (var i:String in data)
{
    trace(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is cast your decoded data as an `Array`:

```
function GetLists()
{
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:51318/api/List/1");
    var ret:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    ret.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(e:Event)
    {
        var jsonData:Array = JSON.decode(ret.data) as Array;
        for each(var obj:Object in jsonData)
        {
            trace(obj["id"] + ": " + obj["description"]);
        }
    }
    ret.load(req);
}
```